# When would you have a Seudas Bris by the Friday night Seuda?

Tags: riddle, brit-milah, meal-seudah, leil-shabbat

How is it possible that you would you have a Seudas Bris by the Friday night Seuda?

Comment: Um, how about if the bris was done late Friday afternoon?

Comment: I think he means "even in an ideal situation" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bris was on 10 Teves (Friday).